# Searching in Array performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, array

We have a table of

```
id|school_id|parent_ids
```

where `parent_ids` is an array of ids.

If we don't have the `school_id` and only `parent_id` to search for, then the query will search through all the table rows in `parent_ids` array, there might be thousands of rows, and `parent_id` might actually be within just few of them.

Does using IN in query for the array column could be a performance barrier in this case?

**EDIT**

Here is the dump of table structure:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for schools_messages
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."schools_messages";
CREATE TABLE "public"."schools_messages" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('schools_messages_id_seq'::regclass),
  "message" jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]'::jsonb,
  "details" jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]'::jsonb,
  "school_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamp(0),
  "updated_at" timestamp(0),
  "parents_ids" int4[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::integer[]
)
;
ALTER TABLE "public"."schools_messages" OWNER TO "prod_schools";

-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table schools_messages
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."schools_messages" ADD CONSTRAINT "schools_messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- ----------------------------
-- Foreign Keys structure for table schools_messages
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."schools_messages" ADD CONSTRAINT "schools_messages_school_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("school_id") REFERENCES "public"."trk_schools" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [Edit] your question. Do **not** post code in comments

Comment: [Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/arrays.html#idm46428711817776)

Comment: Kindly check the structure above

Comment: Index? There does not seem to be an index on the field. Not a postgres guy, but on SQL Server a foreign key constraint does NOT automatically create an index.

Comment: @JackDouglas will you please describe more? I am not getting your point

Comment: Have another table `id,parent_id` which has one row for each of the elements of your current array, so the primary key of the new table is `id,parent_id`. Then drop the array from your current table. That's the basic idea if you can redesign — then you will be using the normal relational features of the database such as joins and regular indexes, which are the right tools for most jobs.

Comment: so, if an array has 3000 id, I will have to create 3000 rows as an alternative, the table size will get very big in a short time I believe, right? each time a message is sent, I will have to add thousands of rows.. is that still ok?

Comment: Kindly check my db design question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196207/searching-in-array-recommended-design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Jack that your schema needs help. But you can still do this. Here we do this with one index lookup, using two core extensions [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) and [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

CREATE INDEX ON public.schools_messages
  USING gist(school_id, parents_ids gist__int_ops);

VACUUM ANALYZE public.schools_messages;

SELECT *
FROM public.schools_messages
WHERE school_id = 42
  OR parent_id @> ARRAY[42];
```

Comment: Would this be efficient when having thousands of  rows, each array in a row has thousands of integers? It seems like searching in a 2D array.. well?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "efficient" it's better than anything else except changing the schema.

Comment: Absolutely, it's better than anything else, but changing the schema is an option too, but I need a recommendation, I thought about adding an array in the parent table, that has foreign ids to the schools_messages table, this way with the parent_id, I can get all the messages parent involved in using one query, but the downside, is that when adding a new message, I will have to add its id to all parents sent to, what do you think?

Comment: @simo I think you need to ask another question and tag it with [tag:database-design] =)

Comment: here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196207/searching-in-array-recommended-design